# How to use ? and catch in Rust?

Tags: exception, rust, try-catch

It seems that [`?` and `catch` have been accepted into Rust](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/44chyr/the_traitbased_exceptions_rfc_has_been_accepted/), but I am not able to use it properly:

```
let x = catch {
    1
}
```

I think this should give me `Ok(1)`. Instead, I get the error:

```
error: expected identifier, found `1`
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         1
   |         ^
```

Is this syntax not yet supported in Rust, or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: Actually, only the question mark operator is in the language right now. That link merely points to an RFC.

Comment: Chances are good that most people don't want to use `catch` anyway. It's unlikely to be a commonly-used thing, in my opinion.

Comment: I would suggest that you accept Alec's answer instead of mine: explaining why the error message is cool and all, but explaining how to actually use `catch` is probably more useful :) No pressure though, and you are free to accept any answer you want to.

Comment: This is a problem with Rust compiler as it fails to output correct error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR: The RFC is accepted, but your syntax is slightly off (unfortunately) and the feature is still gated.**

*See Alec's excellent answer on how to actually use `catch`.*

---

I encourage you to read the *full* error log:

> ```
> error: expected identifier, found `1`
>  --> <anon>:2:21
>   |
> 2 |     let x = catch { 1 };
>   |                     ^
>
> error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `catch` in this scope
>  --> <anon>:2:13
>   |
> 2 |     let x = catch { 1 };
>   |             ^^^^^ not found in this scope
>
> error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
> ```

The clue is in the second error message:

> cannot find struct, variant or union type `catch` in this scope

which really lets us know that `catch` is not recognized as a keyword by the compiler.

Since `catch` looks like any regular word, what happens is that the compiler attempts to parse this as building a `struct` or `enum`. Indeed, the syntax for building a `struct` or `enum` is:

```
struct X { name: i32 }

let x = X { name: 1 };
```

Therefore, the compiler sees `<identifier> {` and expects it to be followed by a list of `<identifier>: <expression>`. It reads `1`, which is not an identifier, and reports the error that `1` is not an identifier.

Answer (score 6):

This is going to sound very dumb, because it kind of is. You need to have

```
#![feature(catch_expr)]

fn main() {
    let x = do catch {
        1
    };
}
```

Basically, `catch`, like `default` and `union`, cannot be made a keyword without breaking backwards compatibility. Since Rust has tried to guarantee that any code on 1.x will still work on 1.y, introducing `default`, `union` and now `catch` into the grammar has been all about figuring out the conflicts. For `union` and `default`, there are none - identifiers are never expected in those positions.

For `catch`, `catch { 1 }` can also be interpreted as a struct literal. Unless you require `do` (a reserved keyword) occur before `catch` - then there is no ambiguity. Yes, this is ugly, and everyone knows it.

Hopefully these nightmares go away when 2.0 comes around and we can break backwards compatibility. Quoted from the [rust-internals discussion around the grammar woes of `catch`](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/grammatical-ambiguity-around-catch-blocks/4807):

> There's a growing list of other syntax we would ultimately like to repurpose in this way, but we generally avoid breaking the ability to run code that worked on 1.x on 1.y where y > x except in cases where the code was exploiting a compiler bug or was just a terrifically rare construction. Our stability guarantees demand we wait until 2.0 for most of these.

Comment: *when 2.0 comes around* — there are no plans for a Rust 2.0, and one might even say there are *anti-plans* — no one is excited to break backwards compatibility due to the reluctance to upgrade in many of the domains that Rust targets.

Comment: @Shepmaster I hope you are wrong. :) TBH, for a lot of these changes, very little code in the wild actually breaks - the problem is that one can imagine code that _could_ break. Making `union` a keyword would probably be a very good idea in the long run - but it should be a very slow process. First come the warnings "`union` will become a keyword, don't use it as a variable", then an error you can disable with a flag, then finally a hard error. Otherwise, Rust's grammar is going to go the same way C++'s did.

Comment: Since the previous comments were made, work in introducing a Rust "2018 Edition" has happened, and new keywords are back on the table!